# Can I have vim do multiline edit?

Tags: vim

I merged a python file using vimdiff, and the result has something like this:

```
def code():
  line 1
  line 2
   line 3
   line 4
   ...
   line n
```

In this state, the indentation is inconsistent. How could I remove all the spaces in front of the lines? I tried in Visual mode, but it's selecting the whole line. Does vim have a multiline edit? Notepad++ allows this with Alt-Shift.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Ctrl-V` to select blocks.

Or, to remove all white-space at the start of all lines in the file:

```
:%s/^\s\+
```

Comment: If you use Ctrl-V then j to select the column to which you want to align your code, hit `<` to shift the code that is behind the column.

Comment: @Benoit : Great trick! I often increase/decrease indentation in the middle of lines : until now I was yanking/pasting spaces !

Comment: What would be the solution if you didn't want to replace white spaces on ALL lines, but on a selection of lines which are not adjacent (e.g. lines 1, 3 and 7)?

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two solutions to your problem :

1. There is a blockwise select mode than you enter by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>. You can select the spaces at the beginning of your lines and hit <kbd>d</kbd>.
2. Alternatively, you can select linewise the line you want to modify by entering visual mode with <kbd>SHift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> (then use down arrow or <kbd>j</kbd> to select). And then use <kbd><</kbd> to remove one indentation level. Use <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the last operation if you want to remove multiple indentation.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> will put you into visual line mode, and then you can press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter a command to execute on only the selected lines.

Answer (score 4):

With VISUAL mode you only have to select all the lines you want to re-indent and hit `=`.

I've never used Notepad++ but I think that what you call multiline edit is achievable with what Vim calls VISUAL BLOCK : instead of `V` hit `<C-v>`. You are then able to select rectangular portions of text. Once you have your column, hit `I` or `A` to enter EDIT mode then `<Esc>` to apply your edit to all the lines. Since you want to remove a single space you have to visually select the column of spaces and hit `x` or `d`.

You can also do it with a simple search/replace, I guess. Or use `:norm`.